# Java: Incompatible Types

Tags: java

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Proj3 {
    public static void main(String[]args){
     // DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00”);
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     int TotalHours = 0;
     int TotalGrade = 0;

     System.out.print("How many courses did you take? ");
     int Courses = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
     System.out.println("");

     int CourseNumber = Courses - (Courses - 1);
     while (Courses > 0){
         System.out.print("Course (" + CourseNumber +"): How many hours? ");
         int Hours = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
         TotalHours = TotalHours + Hours;

         System.out.print("Course (" + CourseNumber +"): Letter grade? ");
         char Grade = s.nextLine().charAt(0);

         if (Grade == 'A'){
             TotalGrade = TotalGrade + (4 * Hours);
            }
         if (Grade == 'B'){
             TotalGrade = TotalGrade + (3 * Hours);
            }
         if (Grade == 'C'){
             TotalGrade = TotalGrade + (2 * Hours);
            }
         if (Grade == 'D'){
             TotalGrade = TotalGrade + (1 * Hours);
            }

         Courses = Courses - 1;
         CourseNumber = CourseNumber + 1;
        }
     Double GPA = TotalGrade / TotalHours;
     System.out.println(df.format(GPA));

    }
}
```

This is for an assignment and I don't know how to fix my problem.
The `Double GPA = TotalGrade / ToutalHours;` line is coming up with the `Incompatible Types` error.

Also I'm supposed to include the `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00”);`line at the beginning of the main but its not working.

Anything is very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 Double GPA = TotalGrade / TotalHours;
```

[**`Autoboxing`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. Hence `Double` is wrapper class for primitive `double` and `Integer` is wrapper class for primitive `int`.

Your `TotalGrade / TotalHours` is resulting in an `int` but you are trying to assign it to object with type `Double`. Do either:

```
double GPA = (double)TotalGrade / TotalHours;
```

or,

```
Double GPA = (double)TotalGrade / TotalHours;
```

Comment: Your first example - you don't cast your divisor/dividend to a `double`.  That will lead to integer division.

Comment: Thanks for the response. my first example will result in integer division `yes` but it will not give the error the OP is having. I am responding to OP's question why he is having `Incompatible Types` error and get around with it. Should i edit it ? please any suggestion will be appreciable

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrapper class `Double`. While your variables `TotalGrade / ToutalHours` are primitive types int. Hence they are incompatible. Using primitive double will solve this issue.

```
double GPA = TotalGrade / ToutalHours;
```

Same for `DecimalFormat` issue, the `format` method doesn't accept wrapper `Double`. So when you use primitive `double` it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code

1. Java allows type promotion but you are trying to promote an int value to Double which is not possible this can be resolved in following two way

> change your Double GPA = TotalGrade / TotalHours;
>
> to Double GPA = (double)TotalGrade / TotalHours;  //this is explicit
>   type casting
>
> or double GPA = TotalGrade/ TotalHours // this type promotion

Second problem is

```
// DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00”);
```

in this line see the closing quotes its wrong change it to `"`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert int To Wrapper class Double.

Replace

```
Double GPA = TotalGrade / TotalHours;
```

With

```
double GPA = TotalGrade /TotalHours;
```

AND you can write

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
```

At begining of main if you want and print it like

```
System.out.println("The Decimal Value is:"+formatter.format(GPA));
```

Comment: do you think that cast to (double)TotalGrade is needed ?